# Want to edit a file in place (substitute a column value) based on a value in another column in the same file

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix, nawk

I want to edit a file in place (substitute a column value) based on a value in another column in same file. I don't want to redirect the output after substitution to another file but rather would want to edit the file in place. Specifically need this because file which needs to be edited will be accessed by no of programs simultaneously and in-place editing is must for this

I tried code below. but this is again writing to input file line by line

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open(FILEIN, "/dummy/chaat/h2") || die("Cannot open file");
@file = <FILEIN>;
seek FILEIN, 0, 0;

foreach $file (@file) {
    @field = split(/\|/, $file);
    print $field[8] . "\n";
    if ($field[8] eq "ROBERT") {
        $file =~ s/JAMES/FUDIK/g;
        print FILEIN $file;
    }
}
```

My sample records are as shown below. Here I want to do inline editing of this. if field 8 is ROBERT then substitute JAMES with FUDIK in field 7

```
Change|sinmg|ewfewf|ewfew|def|fdfd|JAMES|rewr|ROBERT|dsf|fe
Change|sinmg|ewfewf|ewfew|def|JAMES|fewf|rewr|BEASLEY|dsf|fe
```

I would appreciate any help on this

Comment: Unless the new field is the exact same size as the previous field, you cannot avoid rewriting the file, use a database if that is your intent.

Comment: @Thor Below answer from TLP is working irrespective of field size

Comment: The `-i` switch may say in-place, but a temporary file is used in the background, see `perlrun(1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'\|' -i -lape 'if ($F[8] eq "ROBERT") { s/JAMES/FUDIK/g }' /dummy/chaat/h2
```

The `-i` option will do the in-place edit. You may wish to restrict the substitution to avoid partial matches, e.g.:

```
s/(?<=\|)JAMES(?=\|)/FUDIK/g
```

Or you can use the `-n` switch instead of `-p` and do

```
s/JAMES/FUDIK/g for @F } print join "|", @F;
```

You should be aware that this in-place edit is in fact writing a new file, and copying over the old. If you want to avoid this, you need to do some serious juggling, and probably lock the file during writing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I tried above command and this is vanishing file content and making it zero byte.

Comment: @Chkusi There is no way that that command truncated your file. It will only *affect* your file if field 8 is ROBERT, and then only change JAMES to FUDIK.

Comment: File is not getting modified. I have displayed log by answering to this question.

Comment: I forgot to escape the `|`, the split string should be `\|`. I have corrected the one-liner, and it should work now.

Comment: Don't forget to check the checkmark beside the answer if you feel it solved your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16745/discussion-between-chkusi-and-tlp)

Comment: Is there anyway that I can pass shell variables to this perl command?. Passing value "ROBERT" from SHELL. Same with JAMES and FUDIK.

Comment: You can access shell variable via the `%ENV` hash, e.g. `$ENV{"ROBERT"}` to access `$ROBERT`, but it does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: Is there any other way of passing shell variables to perl apart from using %ENV hash ?

Comment: No there is nothing wrong. But you mentioned its not a good idea to declare these variables as ENV variables and refer them in perl. Thats the reason why i asked if you know any other way.

Comment: @chku Passing input to perl can be done in better ways then using ENV, is what I meant. If it is a one-liner, using shell variables is just silly. If you want to save typing time: copy and paste.

Comment: This does *not* edit the file in place.  It creates a temporary file and renames it to the original file, breaking hard links in the process.  If using temporary files causes a race condition, this solution does not solve it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Perhaps you did not notice, but I do mention that in my answer.

Comment: @TLP and William Pursell.. I would be executing this command from different server locations which accesses same file for writing,may be at same time or different time. At all those times, I would be replacing some string with another string at different places in file. Would this command serves this purpose?.

Comment: Also I would like this string replacement to be field specific which means substitution should only look for 8th field in entire pipe delimited line for replacement.

Comment: @Chkusi I'm not sure what you think will be different. It will affect all target files the same way. If you're going to be using it a lot, I would recommend writing it into a script.

Comment: @TLP..Here is clear and precise explanation. This command will be executed from different places with different search and substitute strings at same/different time to access/write same file. I was checking with you if all these substitutions happening on same file from different places will be effective. I understand that above command do in-place edit is in fact writing a new file, and copying over the old. Are there chances that any kind of overwriting is possible here?

Comment: I assume that if multiple processes are trying to access/modify the file, there is a chance that things go awry. You should ask a new question on that topic.

Comment: @TLP.. Thanks for all your help. Sure will test this and do some research on this. If i still have any questions,then i would ask experts here.  Can you please let me know what modification needs to be done for above command for string replacement to be field specific which means substitution should only look for 8th field in entire pipe delimited line for replacement?..

Comment: You already know how to access the field numbers. Although `$F[8]` refers to the *9th* field, since perl arrays' starting index is 0. So `$F[8] =~ s/foo/bar/g` would alter the 9th field in the `@F` array. Remember, though, to print the `@F` array and not `$_`.